# Python, Tkinter - What happens when you set the size of a window by geometry() that its size will no longer change with elements' size on it?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

When you create a new widget and put it up on a window using `grid` or demolish one using say `grid_forget` then the containing window's dimension grows or shrinks respectively depending on the size of newly added or deleted widget.
But when you set the size of containing window to a specific amount using `geometry()` then above actions will not affect the size of the containing window anymore.

Is there any trick to make containing window's size responsive again (based on its elements' size) after you had set manually its size once?

take a look at below slip of code:

```
import Tkinter

def func1():
    l1.destroy()
    w.update()
    print w.winfo_width(), "x", w.winfo_height()

def func2():
    print w.geometry(str(w.winfo_width()+10)+"x"+str(w.winfo_height()+10))

w=Tkinter.Tk()

l1=Tkinter.Label(w, width=20, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", text='             ')
l2=Tkinter.Label(w, width=20, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", text='             ')
c=Tkinter.Button(w, text="clik", command=func1)
c2=Tkinter.Button(w, text="clik2", command=func2)

l1.grid(row=1, column=0)
l2.grid(row=1, column=1)
c.grid(row=0, column=1)
c2.grid(row=2, column=1)
w.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
w.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

w.mainloop()
```

If you first clicked on `c` button the `w` window would shrink after `l1` label disappeared. 
But if you first clicked on `c2` button (assigning a new value explicitly with `geometry`) size would become constant and no longer change with size of widgets on it (click on `c1` would not change window size based on remaining widgets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the window geometry by passing an empty string to the `geometry` method.

Example:

```
def func1():
    w.geometry("")
    ...
```